# Regressing a random variable to $n$ other random variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable, I would like to regress it on $Z= (Z_1, \ldots, Z_p)$ other random variables and to find the residual. In this case, I use the model $X = Z\beta$, where $\beta$ is a $p \ x \ 1$ vector. I understand that the line of best fit will be $(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^TX$. However, will there be issues of singularity inside the $(Z^TZ)$ matrix because $n=1 < p$?

Comment: Yes, $(Z^T Z)$ can still fail to be invertible... in that case you can use a least squares fitting.

Comment: @TravisJ I was under the assumption that least squares would require invertibility, do you know what you mean by the least squares fitting? thanks!

Comment: Solving the normal equations that you are doing there will find a least squares (linear) fit to your data.  But, if $(Z^T Z)$ isn't invertible, you can find a matrix as close as possible to the inverse of that matrix... and use it instead.

Comment: @user321627: see the Wikipedia link that I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the [normal equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Inverting_the_matrix_of_the_normal_equations) is obtained by using the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse). The pseudoinverse is well-defined for any matrix.